# Global and local variables in function combined with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, global, local

Why is this possible? When I click on the button it switches  to "I have been clicked". However, "action" is a local object of the function. How can the function cause a global change?

I'd expected that I need to set action global in the function via "global action".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#Creates tk object
win = tk.Tk()

win.title("TEST")

alabel = ttk.Label(win, text = "A Label")
alabel.grid(column=0, row=0)

#function
def click_me():
    action.configure(text="I have been clicked")
    alable.configure(foreground='red')
    alable.configure(text='a red label')

#adding a button
action = ttk.Button(win, text="Click me", command = click_me)
action.grid(column=1, row=0)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: is the the type in `click_me` intentional (`alable` whereas you have `alabel` outside the function)?

Comment: *"`action` is a local object of the function"* What makes you think that? `action` is clearly defined in the global scope.

Comment: A function can read or _mutate_  an object bound to a global name. But it can't assign to a global name without a `global` directive, because that binds a new object to the name, and without the directive the new object is bound to a local name. But there's no new object here.

Comment: BTW, you have a couple of typos in `click_me`: you have "alable" instead of "alabel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, "action" is a local object of the function.

That is incorrect. Until you assign something to `action` within the function, it refers to the global variable `action`.

Because you are calling a method on `action` rather than setting `action` to a new value, you are modifying the object that `action` points to.